# Does the kanji 両 have the reading teru (てる)?

Tags: readings

[jisho.org's entry for 両](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%A1%20%23kanji) says

> Kun:
> てる、 ふたつ

If true, in what context do you use these kun readings?

Answer (score 2):

In short, those kun readings are old, and by and large, not in current and popular use. They might however be found in literary text, especially for an archaic effect. てる seems to be a typo or scanno of テール.

### 両{テール} (*tael*)

There was an old currency and unit of weight called [tael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tael) which was written 兩 whose variants include 両. Because of this you might find 両 annotated with テール - tēru, but it's exclusively for the currency and unit.

I'm not aware of a テル / てる / teru variant, while it's not entirely implausible. Even if it was used, it might be a stretch to say these "readings" are kun. You can annotate 野球 with ベースボール, but that doesn't make it a kun reading of 野球.

### 両{ふた}つ (*a pair*)、両人{ふたり} (*a couple*)、両{ふた}親{おや} (*parents*)

Example: https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000038/files/334_15956.html

> 両{ふた}親{おや}に早く死に別れて、たった二人の姉弟ですから、互いに力にしていたのが、今では別れ別れになって、生き死にさえわからんようになりました。

I think the 両つ usage is largely replaced with 二つ, and ふたおや is a bit more archaic than りょうしん.

Similarly, you might encounter 双{ふた}つ in old text, especially when something is in *a pair*, like human eyes, but more recently you simply write 二つ.

Comment: This made me wonder if たばこ is a valid kun reading for 煙草. Interestingly, this is also Portuguese.

Comment: @aguijonazo Jisho at least considers it to be gikun or jukujikun.

Comment: Note this Japanese kanji site has ふた・つ but not てる: https://www.kanjipedia.jp/kanji/0007152100